# Azure DevOps ，git fetch failed with exit code 128，fatal：Authentication failed for

Tags: git, azure, pipeline

When I use Azure DevOps Pipeline ，I received this error:
`"fatal：could not read username for ‘http：xx.xx.xx.xx:’ No such device or address, git fetch failed with exit code 128".`

When:

1. I login to the agent machine;
2. Use the command `git clone http://xx.xx.x.x/x/xx/` (Azure DevOps repo); and
3. Input username and passwd

It shows `“fatal：Authentication failed for ...”`. I tried using PAT and
SSH，But they both failed.  The port 443 and 43 is isolation
attentions： is http， not https

Answer (score 1):

Generate a new SSH key.
Go back to your Git account and remove the old SSH key and add the newly generated SSH key.
For best practice always set SSH key password instead of leaving it blank.

Comment: thanks your reponse,  i hava try it, but it doesn't work.  otherwise the port 43 is isolated